# Display category parents and their children

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, wp-list-categories

I would like to display all the categories related to a post, along with their parents.

Currently I have something like this: Dog, Female, London, Newborn

I'm using this code:

```
$categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( '</br> ', 'twentytwentyone' ) );
            if ( $categories_list ) {
                printf(
                    '<p class="cat-links"> ' . ( $categories_list ) . ' </p></div>'
                );
            }
```

But I would like to also display the parent category as such:

<----------->

Type: Dog

Gender: Female

Location: London

Age: Newborn

<----------->

Note: I have tried simply writing HTML to group these as such

Type

Gender

Location

Age

This doesn't work because the categories listed are not ordered, therefore sometimes the output will be something like (Gender: Dog, Location: Female ,Type: London)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: documentation said this: `For a more powerful, list-based function, see wp_list_categories().` which is probably what you need

Comment: @Kazz I have come across this, tried to make it work, but it hasn't. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(get_the_category() as $category){
                echo ($category->parent?get_category($category->parent)->name.': ':'').$category->name.'</br>';
            }
```

This worked!